# How to apply ad hoc IDE styling in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Due to the nature of the way we work, we often find ourselves with 2 or more versions of the same project open at one time in different Visual Studio sessions. Unfortunately, these are just stacked on the task bar so without going to a source code file and inspecting the path, we can't readily tell them apart.

Is there a way to apply some ad hoc styling to the IDE to be able to tell them apart more readily? Something like theme would be ideal but at a session level.

N.B. this isn't something we'd want to check into source control so we want to avoid having say, marker files in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SolutionColor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Wumpf.SolutionColor&ssr=false#overview) extension allows to set the color of the title bar on a per solution basis.

Comment: Perfect - just what I was after!